# Why do I have four different startup disks on dual boot setup(refind) and how do I eliminate them?

Tags: dual-boot

1. Boot efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi from efi
2. Boot boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic.efi.signed from 23 gib ext4 volume
3. Boot macos from preboot
4. Boot macos from SSD